# How to use multiple models for tag_cloud?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

**_tags.html.erb**

```
#Version 1 (Just lists out habits tags)
<% tag_cloud Habit.tag_counts, %w{s m l} do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
<% end %>

#Version 2
<% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class %>
<% end %>
```

How can we get it where it list's out the **current_user**'s habits AND goals, valuations, quantifieds? `f.text_field :tag_list` is in the _form of each of these four models, which are also separate tables in the database.

I also added the below code to each of the four models. Here's is how it looks for valuations:

**Helper**

```
module ValuationsHelper
  include ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsHelper
end
```

**Controller**

```
class ValuationController < ApplicationController
  def tag_cloud
    @tags = Valuation.tag_counts_on(:tags)
  end
end
```

and for the **User Model**

```
  User.tag_counts_on(:tags)
  acts_as_tagger
  acts_as_taggable
```

I'm using the **acts-as-taggable-on** gem, which I implemented from [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging). Please let me know if you need any further code or explanation =]

Comment: Can you post your model has_many belongs _to's

Comment: If User.rb has_many habits and Habit belongs_to User you can use the tag cloud of current_user.habits.tag_counts

Comment: Habits, Goals, Valuations and Quantifieds are seperate tables in your database?

Comment: That's correct @Zippo9 sorry I didn't see your comment sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model called `Tagalicious`.

Since you want it in the sidebar put this in the application_controller:

```
before_action :tag_cloud

def tag_cloud
  @tags = Tagalicious.tag_counts_on(:tags)
end
```

Then in the helper:

```
module TagaliciousHelper
  include ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsHelper
end
```

Then in the model:

```
class Tagalicious < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :habit
  belongs_to :goal
  belongs_to :quantified
  belongs_to :valuation
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

tag_cloud:

```
<% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag), :class => css_class %>
<% end %>
```

Hopefully that will clarify some things. I can't figure out how to make this line in your various models `<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>` point to the `Tagalicious` model.

This is something we can go over in chat if you want or maybe try another question for that specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use the method with in the gem: **acts_as_tagger** in the User model to set up tags specific to the user. Example for acts_as_taggable_on gem docs:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_tagger
    end

    class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_taggable_on :locations
    end

     @some_user.tag(@some_photo, :with => "paris, normandy", :on => :locations)
     @some_user.owned_taggings
     @some_user.owned_tags

    @some_user.tag(@some_photo, :with => "paris, normandy", :on => :locations, :skip_save => true)
```

In Your Case you will need to set up a join table that includes the ids of: Habits, Goals, Valuations and Quantifieds and then you should be able to create a variable to call the tag count on that table or individual set up each Habits, Goals, Valuations and Quantifieds in your views for a specific user. Either way it should look something like this:

```
    @tags = YourModel.tag_counts_on(**context**)
```

### UPDATE ATTEMPT

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      acts_as_tagger
    end

    class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
      # This goes for Valuation, Goal, and Quantified too.
      acts_as_taggable_on :combine_tags
    end

    class CombineTag < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :habit
      belongs_to :goal
      belongs_to :quantified
      belongs_to :valuation
    end
```

I tried migrating this:

```
    class CreateCombineTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :combine_tags do |t|
          t.valuation_id :integer
          t.goal_id :integer
          t.quantified_id :integer
          t.habit_id :integer

          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
    end
```

but I got `undefined method 'valuation_id' for #<ActiveRecord::` I don't know if `has_many` and `belongs_to` is enough to join the models I'm going to assume yes.

Then what do I do with `@tags = YourModel.tag_counts_on(**context**)`? What does context mean? Does this go in **_tags.html.erb**? If so would it look like this:

```
<% @tags = CombineTag.tag_counts_on(**???**)
<% tag_cloud @tags.tag_counts, %w{s m l} do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi @Zippo9 I added a bounty to this question because I couldn't get your answer to work. If you can be of further assistance I would greatly greatly appreciate it :)