# Can create_join_table only take 2-3 arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I've tried a bunch of variations of this **migration** file:

```
class CombineTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :habits, :valuations, :quantifieds, :goals do |t|

        t.timestamps null: false
    end
    t.index :habits, [:habit_id, :tag_list], :valuations, [:valuation_id, :tag_list], :quantifieds, [:quantified_id, :tag_list] :goals, [:goal_id, :tag_list]
  end
end
```

but I keep getting this error upon running `rake db:migrate`:

```html
Anthony-Gallis-MacBook-Pro:pecoce galli01anthony$ rake db:migrate
== 20150506172844 CombineTags: migrating ======================================
-- create_join_table(:habits, :valuations, :quantifieds, :goals)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (4 for 2..3)/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:248:in `create_join_table'
```

This is just one step in trying to achieve my ultimate goal: [How to use multiple models for tag_cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906256/how-to-use-multiple-models-for-tag-cloud)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [create_join_table](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_join_table) accept only 3 args (last of them is optionals, look at link). So, you can't create join table for 3 tables use this method.

In you case you should create join table use [create_table](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table) and specify correspond reference fields.