# How to make a multi model tag_cloud with a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, rails-activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a **join table**

```
create_table "combine_tags", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "habit_id"
  t.integer "valuation_id"
  t.integer "goal_id"
  t.integer "quantified_id"
end
```

whose purpose is to make a tag_cloud work for multiple models. I put this in the **application_controller**

```
def tag_cloud
  @tags = CombineTag.tag_counts_on(:tags)
end
```

My **tag_cloud** looks like this:

```
<% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag), :class => css_class %>
<% end %>

# or this depending on which works:

<% tag_cloud CombineTag.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
<% end %>
```

I have this line in the **_form** of all the models: `<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>`

**combine_tags_helper**

```
module CombineTagsHelper
  include ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsHelper
end
```

**models**

```
class CombineTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :habit
  belongs_to :goal
  belongs_to :quantified
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_taggable
end

class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base # Same goes for other models
  has_many :combine_tags
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

Please let me know if you need further explanation or **[code](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging)** to help you help me :)

- **[acts-as-taggable-on @ github](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)**

Comment: Can you tell me in brief what the exact behavior you are looking for to implement ?

Comment: I know how to make a tag_cloud with one model, but I can't get it to work with multiple models where if I created a tag called `run` under habits & under goals that the tag_cloud would represent the tag's usage in proportion. Does that help @ArupRakshit?

Comment: can you brief me about the usecase ? why you need _join_table_ trying to understand ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I came to this attempt based on the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906256/how-to-use-multiple-models-for-tag-cloud so maybe you'll find this question more helpful. Ultimtaely I'm trying to create a tag_cloud using multiple models. I'm open to chatting if you need to. I'm available for the next hour :)

Comment: can you join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79959/r-o-r ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, You could use polimorphing. Please, see [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

In Your case, Model could be next:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true 
....

class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, as: :taggable
....

class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, as: :taggable
....
```

And in migrations:

```
create_table :tags , force: true do |t|
  t.references :taggable, polymorphic: true, index: true
  t.timestamps null: false    
end
```

After this You can:

```
@tags = Tag.include(:taggable)
@tags.each do |tag|
  type = tag.taggable_type # string, some of 'habit', 'goal' etc
  id = tag.taggable_id # id of 'habit', 'goal' etc
end
```